# Validating a JWT in node.js

Tags: javascript, authentication, node.js, base64, jwt

I'm trying to parse and validate a JWT token in node.js based on this sample (authored in .NET): https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/blob/master/Samples/Asp.net/AuthenticationTokenSample/JsonWebToken.cs

Here is my node js javascript that validates the token:

```
var validateSignature = function(key, claims, envelope, signature) {
    var hasher = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    hasher.update(key + "JWTSig");
    var key = hasher.digest('binary');
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);
    hmac.update(envelope + '.' + claims);
    var out = hmac.digest('base64');
    console.log(out);
    console.log(signature);
    console.log(out === signature);
}
```

Now, the very weird thing is - it almost works. Here's the output of the three console.log statements:

```
pEwNPJ+LUHBdvNx631UzdyVhPFUOvFY8jG3x/cP81FE=
pEwNPJ-LUHBdvNx631UzdyVhPFUOvFY8jG3x_cP81FE
false
```

It seems suspicious to me that the hashes are both the same except for the +-/_=

Anybody spot my mistake? Something to do with my base64 encoding.

**UPDATE**

I played some more and there seems to be something funky going on with base64 encoding here. The following code in node js:

```
console.log(signature);
var b = new Buffer(signature, 'base64');
console.log(b.toString('base64'));
```

yields:

```
pEwNPJ-LUHBdvNx631UzdyVhPFUOvFY8jG3x_cP81FE
pEwNPJLUHBdvNx631UzdyVhPFUOvFY8jG3xcP81F
```

Which seems very odd, right?

Comment: It could be that node's hmac function outputs a web or URL safe hash and the rest of your code is correct.

Comment: Something like that, I just updated the

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Timothy Meade for commenting and pushing me in the right direction.

Node's Buffer type generates standard Base64 with +, / and =

There is a URL safe base64 encoding as mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

It replaces + with -, / with _ and = is optional. The token that is passed on the QueryString (d'uh) is a URL safe version. Hence the difference.

Code was fixed by a simple:

```
out = out.replace('+','-').replace('/','_').replace('=','');
```

Comment: An old post, but still. Your code won't replace all of the occurrences.

`out = out.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '');`

will work though :)

Comment: replace(/=/g, '') replaces all equals characters even if they are not at the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this library a while ago, I guess you can use some of the code. It is supposed to run in both node.js and in a modern browser.

- [JWT library for javascript](https://github.com/andreassolberg/oicjs)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact method that you were trying to use, but I believe it is the preferred way to validate a JWT in NodeJS.  Note that I am using the NPM `base64url` library to convert between base64Url (the default encoding for a JWT) and `base64` (what NodeJS expects for the verification function).

Also note, you need a public and private keypair to sign and verify respectively.  I have included the private and public keys that were used to sign and verify this JWT at the bottom of this post.

```
const base64 = require('base64url');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const verifyFunction = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
const fs = require('fs');

// The sample JWT from https://jwt.io/
const JWT = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.POstGetfAytaZS82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExREkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQGxHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8OcaarA8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618iYv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA';

// This just gets the value of the public key (same as the one at bottom of this post)
const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/id_rsa_pub.pem', 'utf8');

// Split the JWT by `.` to get each part
const jwtHeader = JWT.split('.')[0];
const jwtPayload = JWT.split('.')[1];
const jwtSignature = JWT.split('.')[2];

// We only need the first two pieces to verify
verifyFunction.write(jwtHeader + '.' + jwtPayload);
verifyFunction.end();

// IMPORTANT: NodeJS expects base64 format, not base64url format!
const jwtSignatureBase64 = base64.toBase64(jwtSignature);

// IMPORTANT: You need to specify that the `jwtSignatureBase64` data is base64 format, 
// otherwise, it will default to Buffer format and return false
const signatureIsValid = verifyFunction.verify(PUB_KEY, jwtSignatureBase64, 'base64');

console.log(signatureIsValid); // true
```

The keys below are from the example JWT [mentioned here](https://jwt.io/).

**Private Key:**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Public Key:**

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnzyis1ZjfNB0bBgKFMSv
vkTtwlvBsaJq7S5wA+kzeVOVpVWwkWdVha4s38XM/pa/yr47av7+z3VTmvDRyAHc
aT92whREFpLv9cj5lTeJSibyr/Mrm/YtjCZVWgaOYIhwrXwKLqPr/11inWsAkfIy
tvHWTxZYEcXLgAXFuUuaS3uF9gEiNQwzGTU1v0FqkqTBr4B8nW3HCN47XUu0t8Y0
e+lf4s4OxQawWD79J9/5d3Ry0vbV3Am1FtGJiJvOwRsIfVChDpYStTcHTCMqtvWb
V6L11BWkpzGXSW4Hv43qa+GSYOD2QU68Mb59oSk2OB+BtOLpJofmbGEGgvmwyCI9
MwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```